# SQL Join table and order them by a multiplied value

Tags: mysql, sql

So, short explained: I wanna get all records from the table games_records ordered by the highest furni value (pricelist_furnis_tradevalue.value) multiplied by the records amount (= games_records.amount). The furni value is in pricelist_furnis_tradevalue. 
Now... The pricelist_furnis_tradevalue has multiple entries for some furnis. I wanna get only the newest entry, therefore it should be ordered by pricelist_furnis_tradevalue.time.
But this query below returns all entries from pricelist_furnis_tradevalue for each furni/record.

```
SELECT *
FROM games_records 
JOIN pricelist_furnis_tradevalue 
    ON games_records.furni = pricelist_furnis_tradevalue.furni
ORDER BY (pricelist_furnis_tradevalue.value*games_records.amount) DESC
```

Here are the structures of the 2 needed tables

games_records

```
id      user        furni       amount      time
1       2           4           40          1338052926
2       4           30          90          1338054046
```

pricelist_furnis_tradevalue

```
id      furni       value       time
1       2           20          1334065379
2       2           50          1334067445
3       2           100         1334092057
4       4           50          1334065375
4       4           20          1334067436
```

I'd appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried selecting `pricelist_furnis_tradevalue.value*games_records.amount` ?

Comment: @njk and define them with AS variable and then ORDER BY variable DESC? **EDIT** Tried it. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the record with the maximum time.

Here is one method:

```
SELECT *
FROM games_records join
     (select furni, max(time) as maxtime
      from pricelist_furnis_tradevalue
      group by furni
     ) as maxf
     on games_records.furni = maxf.furni JOIN
     pricelist_furnis_tradevalue 
     ON games_records.furni = pricelist_furnis_tradevalue.furni and
        pricelist_furnis_tradevalue.time = maxf.maxtime
ORDER BY (pricelist_furnis_tradevalue.value*games_records.amount) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT *, pricelist_furnis_tradevalue.value*games_records.amount AS 'mult' FROM games_records 
    JOIN pricelist_furnis_tradevalue 
    ON games_records.furni = pricelist_furnis_tradevalue.furni) a
ORDER BY a.mult DESC
```